# Change datasource in the same tranformation ETL

Tags: etl, database-migration, pentaho-spoon

I have a transformation to extract data for a database but the database source has many tables with different names. The database does have a structure consistent with my transformation, e.g: Events_1, Events_2, Events_3.

It possible change the connection parameters for the extraction of all tables dynamically? I want to extract all data with just one job that will still work when there is a new insert or a new table like Events_600.

Screen-shot of DB:

[image: Settings of the connection]

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables in the transformation and use them to set the connection and even to change the source table.

You will need a job to run through the list of variable values, then once for each row pass those values as parameters to the transformation, for example.

Comment: I know how to set the connection with variables for a database but i´m not sure how with change the source table, do you have somethig idea? thaks for answering

Comment: In a table input step you can also use variables: “select * from ${TABLE_NAME}”. Just need to tick the box “replace variables in script”